# How to create a {key:value} object from two variables?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I want to create an object of type `{key:value}` where the key name is variable. Such object must be provided to [`chrome.storage.<storageType>.set(keys, function(){...})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Storage/StorageArea/set)

There are **a lot** of related questions on SO with working answers, but I was not able to find a suitable explanation of the problem. It boils down to setting a property on a JSON object. I did this test:

```
var desiredKey = "123",
    desiredValue = "Value for key 123",
    foo;

// 1-The basic: Using a literal
console.log({ "123": desiredValue });

// 2-The problem occurs when the key name is not a literal
console.log({ desiredKey: desiredValue });

// 3-The solution is to assign a key explicitely
foo = {};
foo[desiredKey] = desiredValue;
console.log(foo);
```

Results:

```
Object { 123: "Value for key 123" }          <-- Literal
Object { desiredKey: "Value for key 123" }   <-- Variable (wrong)
Object { 123: "Value for key 123" }          <-- Assignment (ok)
```

**Questions:**

- Why does method 2 fail? What is stored? the reference/address of `desiredKey`?
- Is method 3 the simplest one? or is there a one instruction solution?

Comment: *"It boils down to setting a property on a JSON object."* No, it doesn't, because this has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you want to do is create an object with a property whose name comes from a variable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for the explanation, that was obviously not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Method 4

[Computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets `[]`, that will be computed as the property name. This is symmetrical to the bracket notation of the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) syntax, which you might have used to read and set properties already.

```js
var desiredKey = "123",
    desiredValue = "Value for key 123",
    foo = { [desiredKey]: desiredValue };

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Surely you knew this was a duplicate question.

Comment: The result is `"123": "Value for key 123"`, that doesn't seem to be the same than `123: "Value for key 123"`, but that may be a difference between a browser console and the site renderer. Also I'm looking for the explanation.

Comment: keys of objects are always strings. the console.log ma yrender different, because it is not part of ecma script.